# Prevent input().split() from throwing an error

Tags: python-3.x, input

I'm writing a simple calculator in which I have the user enter arithmetic operations of 3 values using the input().split() functions. I'm wondering if, in case the user enters less or more than 3 values, there is a way to prevent the program from throwing a "not enough values to unpack/too many values to unpack" error and instead lets me handle it with an "else:" condition or something similar where I could print something more helpful on the screen? Or is there an alternative to this altogether?

```
num1, operator, num2 = input("enter operation: ").split()

num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)

if operator == "+":
  print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1+num2))

# etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical approach in Python is to try an operation and catch the error if there is one. Here you would catch the `ValueError` and act accordingly:

```
try:
    num1, operator, num2 = input("enter operation: ").split()

    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)

    if operator == "+":
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, num1+num2))

except ValueError:
    print("you didn't enter enough values")
```

You could also wrap this in some sort of loop to ask again if the value is bad.

This approach is listed in the [python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html) under:

> EAFP
>   Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Answer (score 1):

Don't unpack the return values. Instead return to a single object, and then check for the length of the object. Like this:

```
obj = input("enter operation: ").split()
if len(obj) == 3:
    num1, operator, num2 = obj
    ...
else:
    ...
```